# How to differentiate between Debit and Credit card? Also, how to find out if it is MasterCard or Visa or something else

Tags: authorize.net, credit-card

I am integrating my application with Authorize.net. I am using the sandbox for testing. I am using the same API for add both credit and debit cards. In one of the response examples it showed the `cardType` as Visa. I wanted to know if it is possible to get the type of card and also the issuer? Because in the response I got, I didn't get these details.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net will not tell the card type or the issuer.

To do this. you need to get a list of BIN (**B**ank **I**dentification **N**umbers) which correlate to card type (debit or credit). You then can compare the BIN number, which is the first 4-9 numbers of the card, to that list which will tell you the card type and also give you the issuer.

Processors like Worldpay and Card Connect make lists like this available. I am unsure if there is a cost or not. I found [this free one](https://www.bindb.com/bin-list.html) but you'll need to massage it a bit to consume it programmatically. [This API](https://binlist.net/) also claims to be free.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I just noticed that we are getting cardType as "Visa" from authorize .net; but i have used the sample card number "4111111111111111". If i try any other number mentioned in this site https://www.rpmware.com/support/customers-&-orders/questions/test-credit-card-numbers
for all other cards except Visa - i tried using CVV as a 4 digit number - but still i get E00015: The field length is invalid for Card Number

Comment: Among the US based card issuers, only American Express using 4 digit CVV numbers. Visa, Master Card, and Discover use three digit CVV numbers.

Comment: @RamAcharya, If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.